# Using Shadowbox with RadGrid

Tags: radgrid, shadowbox

I have added the Shadowbox on my page and it works fine when I have an anchor tag on the form:

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk rel="shadowbox">Open with Shadowbox</a>
```

I also created a dynamic HyperLink control which was added to a placeholder on my page and it worked fine.

But when I add rel="shadowbox" to the anchor link which is generated by GridHyperLinkColumn of the RadGrid control, nothing happens and the shadowbox doesn't work.

Is there any known issues in using Shadowbox and GridHyperLinkColumn of Telerik RadGrid?

If not, how could I configure it properly?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shadowbox.Init() should have been placed after the Grid is fully loaded not at $(document).ready(...

fixed!